# Is that possible to get User post from liked page of facebook using facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

Hi right now i am trying to get all post of user that post on particular page. i am using that method for get first all pages that logged in user Liked.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/likes"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              
                            //   NSLog(@"reselut %@",result);
                              
                              /* handle the result */
                          }];
```

Then for particular Page feed i get all post using bellow method:

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/123456789/feed" //as documentation said that need to put page-id
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              
                               NSLog(@"reselut %@",result);
                              /* handle the result */
                          }];
```

I read and trying to implimetation using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/page/feed there is said.

---

> /{page-id}/feed
>
> The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this page, or by others on this page. There are other edges which provide filtered versions of this edge:

```
/{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.
/{page-id}/tagged shows only the posts that this page was tagged in.
/{page-id}/promotable_posts shows only the posts that can be boosted (includes unpublished and scheduled posts).
```

All of these derivative edges share the exact same reading structure, however /feed should be used for all publishing purposes.

But i would like to get only those post that posted by logged in user in to particular page. is that possible or not. and if yes then please guide me on this.